# Error in the test before installing Fedora to Mac (next to OSX)

Tags: linux, mac, usb, installation, fedora

I'm trying to install Fedora 29 next to OSX on my macbook air. I downloaded the image and verified the checksum. Then I formatted usb to OSX Extended Journaled file system, and created bootable usb using

```
diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2s2
sudo dd bs=1m if=./Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-29-1.2.iso  of=/dev/rdisk2
```

However, when I start my mac from the USB with the option testing & installing Fedora, I get the following error

[image]

This is not the first time that I'm installing Fedora to my mac, but I was getting the same error before, but still the media allows me to install it if I directly try to install it without testing it, so what is wrong ? why am I getting this error ?

**Edit:**

As I've stated, the checksum is OK

```
grep '^SHA256' *-CHECKSUM | awk -F '[()=]' '{ print $4 "  " $2 }' | shasum -a 256 -c
Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-29-1.2.iso: OK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem;

> You are encountering this bug because of the way OSX handles USB
>   devices.  You run the dd command, which wipes the drive and does all
>   it's fun stuff.  Now, what Fedora is looking for is the drive to just
>   be as is once it finishes writing it.  Unfortunately, OSX finishes the
>   dd command and then immediately automounts the drive.  This, of
>   course, triggers a whole bunch of system indexing tools, writing
>   countless amounts of hidden .whatever files.  This, in turn, changes
>   the drive as the dd command saw it.  Therefore, the data sum that the
>   Fedora media checker is expecting is not the same, as the drive's
>   contents have been changed.
>
> Truthfully, you are safe to just go to town without verifying the
>   drive.  Either that, or install Disk Arbitrator to block drive
>   automounting and then run dd again....will work without a hitch.

Taken from here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1282244

Comment: I thought most ISOs use a read-only filesystem (like iso9660), so mounting it still means no new files can be written... I guess Fedora doesn't

Comment: I  just love it when software does what it thinks I want instead of waiting for me to tell it. BTW, since you're using `dd`, there's no point in formatting the USB first because dd doesn't pay attention to what's already there.

Comment: @Joe Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks for sharing.