# Fedora installation media does not recognise the hard drive in mac

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mac, fedora

As a continuation of my [previous](https://superuser.com/questions/1389877/error-in-the-test-before-installing-fedora-to-mac-next-to-osx/1389905#1389905) question,

I'm trying to install Fedora to my mac, and now I can come to the beginning of installation step without an error, but during the installation process, the media does not recognise the hard drive in my mac. I have googled it this problem, and all the answers are saying something about changing somethings in BIOS, but in the previous installations, I were able to see the hard drive, so how to solve this problem ?

Edit:

Apparently, I can see a disk of size 32GB, but none of the partitions in my disk has 32GB size.

```
[liveuser@localhost ~]$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0  1.7G  1 loop
loop1         7:1    0  6.5G  1 loop
├─live-rw   253:0    0  6.5G  0 dm   /
└─live-base 253:1    0  6.5G  1 dm   /run/install/source
loop2         7:2    0   32G  0 loop
└─live-rw   253:0    0  6.5G  0 dm   /
sda           8:0    1  7.8G  0 disk
├─sda1        8:1    1  1.8G  0 part /run/initramfs/live
├─sda2        8:2    1  9.8M  0 part
└─sda3        8:3    1 20.5M  0 part
[liveuser@localhost ~]$ blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="2018-10-25-00-07-35-00" LABEL="Fedora-WS-Live-29-1-2" TYPE="iso9660" PTUUID="7c3f77cf" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="7c3f77cf-01"
/dev/sda2: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL="ANACONDA" UUID="9415-D610" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="7c3f77cf-02"
/dev/sda3: UUID="133f77e2-97a8-3d0f-8382-7c190bd63438" LABEL="ANACONDA" TYPE="hfsplus" PARTUUID="7c3f77cf-03"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: LABEL="Anaconda" UUID="8867ebfa-3896-4b40-8c83-b0584ecf77b4" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/live-rw: LABEL="Anaconda" UUID="8867ebfa-3896-4b40-8c83-b0584ecf77b4" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/live-base: LABEL="Anaconda" UUID="8867ebfa-3896-4b40-8c83-b0584ecf77b4" TYPE="ext4"
[liveuser@localhost ~]$ parted
WARNING: You are not superuser.  Watch out for permissions.
/dev/mapper/control: open failed: Permission denied
Failure to communicate with kernel device-mapper driver.
Incompatible libdevmapper 1.02.150 (2018-08-01) and kernel driver (unknown version).
Error: No device found
Retry/Cancel? sudo parted
parted: invalid token: sudo
Retry/Cancel? cancel
[liveuser@localhost ~]$ gparted
bash: gparted: command not found...
Similar command is: 'parted'
[liveuser@localhost ~]$
```

Comment: I'm assuming you can run Fedora "live" ok before installing, does it recognize any hard drives then? In `/dev` or with `lsblk` or `blkid` or gnome-disk-utility or `parted` / gparted, etc?

Comment: I checked last night (from the disk app on Fedora); it was detecting only the usb that installation media was on

Comment: That's an onion in the ointment... I'm not sure what else to try, except search for others who've already had & solved the same problem with Fedora

Comment: @Xen2050 All have solved by changing SATA mode in their BIOS to AHCI; mac does not have BIOS, it uses EFI.

Comment: @Xen2050 See my edit please; apparently the usb stick is not the only hard drive I can see.

Comment: Looks like 8GB sda is the only "real" drive there, loop2 isn't a real drive (looks like it's part of the live / filesystem. I'm not sure what to do to make it see the hard drives, is there any settings you can see/change in the mac before it boots an OS? Maybe searching by it's make & model would find something, what make/model is it?

Comment: @Xen2050  macbook air early 2015

Comment: Google has a couple hits for installing Fedora to a macbook air 13 (early 2015) and they don't mention anything other than to create some free space on the hard drive in macos first... I doubt that's the problem...

Comment: @Xen2050 Yeah, in fact when i insralled it before, there were no such problem and that was with a broken media; now the media is Ok, but cant see the ssd.

Comment: Maybe the hard drive is broken?

Comment: @Xen2050 i have osx installed on it; if it was broken, i couldnt use osx on olit i guess.

Comment: True... maybe it's a weird version of Fedora then, maybe an older/newer one will work, or a different distro. Try a Debian or Ubuntu or the european one with a gecko logo... suse?

Comment: @Xen2050  ut is fedora 29; i will try it with 28, the ines that were working was also 28.

Comment: @Xen2050 i am trying  28 now, and it recognizes as before; thanks a lot men. I will report it as a bug of 29.

Comment: That's good news... I suppose I'll consolidate my comments into an answer, since *eventually* they led to a solution...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Q: I'm assuming you can run Fedora "live" ok before installing, does it recognize any hard drives then? In /dev or with lsblk or blkid or gnome-disk-utility or parted / gparted, etc?

  - A: I checked last night (from the disk app on Fedora); it was detecting only the usb that installation media was on

That shouldn't happen...

It's a macbook air early 2015, and Google says installing Fedora to a macbook air 13 (early 2015) shouldn't need anything other than creating some free space on the hard drive in macos first... I doubt that's the problem...

You installed it before with Fedora 28, and there were no such problems... since the hard drive works (runs macos x OK) it could be something wrong with that version of Fedora. Try an older/newer version, or a different distro entirely like a Debian or Ubuntu or suse.

Result: Fedora 28 works & recognizes the hard drive as before; it must be a bug of Fedora 29.